# Why this text wraps in smaller screen size?

Tags: css, media-queries, word-wrap

I have this [site](http://jcubic.pl/new) and on screen size smaller then 725px the footer navigations shows as two lines. I can fix it using `white-space: nowrap;` but I want to know why it's happening, the text have lot of space left. The same happen to copyright notice, but on smaller size.

the html for the nav look like this:

```
<footer>
    <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="https://jcubic.wordpress.com" rel="">blog</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="">projects</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="">tutorials</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="">portfolio</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" rel="">poezja</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    ...
</footer>
```

and css:

```
footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
footer nav {
    position: absolute;
    left: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
}
footer nav ul {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
footer nav ul li:after {
    content: "•";
    margin: 0 10px;
}
footer nav ul li {
    float: left;
}
footer nav ul li:last-child:after {
    content: "";
}
footer #copy {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 801px) {
    footer #copy {
        right: 60px;
    }
}
footer #copy p {
    margin: 0;
}
footer nav ul li a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
    footer {
        height: 40px;
    }
    footer nav {
        left: 50%;
        top: 0;
    }
    footer nav ul {
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
    }
    footer #copy {
        left: 50%;
        bottom: -20px;
    }
    footer #copy p {
        position: relative;
        left: -50%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which browser you are using...seems to be working fine in IE10 and Chrome.

Comment: @RahulR. Google Chrome on Ubuntu.

Comment: Not sure, but OS shouldnt affect anything on browser. I just copy pasted your code in fiddler and footer is coming fine.
Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rahulr/wFcut/

Comment: @RahulR. Your fiddle wraps into two lines on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

Add a minimum width to your body. When the viewport gets smaller than that value, scrollbars will appear.

```
body {
   min-width: 800px;
}
```

Comment: I don't want scrollbars, I want page to be 100% width on a phone and tablet.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you have to much text on one line. So the obvious thing the browser does is put it under each other when it doesn't fit in one line anymore. If you don't want that, either you use your own solution (white-space) or mine. Or you resize the text so it does fit on one line...

Comment: But the text should fit because it's smaller then the container. There is plenty of room there.

Answer (score 1):

You have the following CSS

```
footer nav {
    left: 50%;
    top: 0;
}
footer nav ul {
    position: relative;
    left: -50%;
}
```

This means that the nav element, since it has the left at 50% of the parent, has an implied maximum width of the remaining 50% (of the parent width).

The fact that after that the ul is moved to the left doesn't make the width bigger.

just change the nav left to a lower value and it will work.